# Give background-size: cover effect via percentage value

Tags: html, css, transition

how can I have the same effect as `background-size: cover;` does, but with percentage values.
I tried

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

but this is not similar. Now you might ask, why I'm not simply using `background-size: cover;` then, and it is because I want to animate the background-image, and you can't animate from `cover` to a `%` value.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage + auto will work in some cases but not all. The `cover` value **automatically** sets **either width OR height** to 100% so that the other dimension fits or overflows the container while maintaining aspect ratio. With percentage + auto you need to figure out which side to fit yourself:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.box-port {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
.box-land {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}
.img-port {
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/400x200/CCC/000);
}
.img-land {
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/200x400/CCC/000);
}
.size-full-width {
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
.size-full-height {
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Using <code>background-size: auto 100%</code> for:</p>
<div class="img-port box-port size-full-height">portraint inside portrait (pass)</div>
<div class="img-land box-port size-full-height">landscape inside portrait (fail)</div>

<p>Using <code>background-size: 100% auto</code> for:</p>
<div class="img-port box-land size-full-width">portraint inside landscape (fail)</div>
<div class="img-land box-land size-full-width">landscape inside landscape (pass)</div>
```

The only solution I could think of is to compare the aspect ratio of the container with that of the background image, then use either `background-size: 100% auto` or `background-size: auto 100%`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was hoping there is a non-comparison solution, but I guess this will be the thing to go then.

Answer (score 0):

have a look [Here, David Walsh Background Animation](http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css), He uses background position: 0 0 ;

```
 @keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: 100% 0; }
  }

#animate-area   { 
width: 560px; 
height: 400px; 
background-image: url(bg-clouds.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;

animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not the question I am asking for. I would like to know how to achieve the same effect as `background-size: cover;` with percentage values.